# Generate volume out of 3d-matrix in cpp

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, 3d

I have a function for generating a 3d-matrix with grey values (char values from 0 to 255). Now I want to generate a 3d-object out of this matrix, e.g. I want to display these values as a 3d-object (in cpp). What is the best way to do that platform-independent and as fast as possible?
I have already read a bit about using OGL, but then I run in the following problem: The matrix can contain up to $4\cdot10^9$ values. When I want to load the complete matrix into the RAM, it will collapse. So a direct draw from the matrix is impossible. Furthermore I only found functions for drawing 2d-images in OGL. Is there a way to draw 3d-pixels in OGL? Or should I rather use another approach?
I do not need a moving functionality (at least not at the moment), I just want to display the data.

Edit 2: For narrowing the question in: Is there a way to draw pixels in 3d-space with OGL taken from a 3d-matrix? I did not find a suitable function, I only found 2d-functions.

Comment: yes, IMHO the question is too broad

Comment: Question refactored, I hope that is better now.

Comment: One suggestion "Volume Rendering": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_ray_casting

Comment: also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352270/Getting-started-with-Volume-Rendering

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is called volume rendering. There are various techniques to achieve it, and ultimately it depends on what you want it to look like.

There is no simple way to do this either. You can't just draw 3d pixels. You can draw using GL_POINTS and have each transformed point raster to 1 pixel, but this is probably completely unsatisfactory for you because it will only draw a some pixels to the screen (you wont see anything on big resolutions).

A general solution would be to just render a cube using normal triangles, for each point. Sort it back to front if you need alpha blending. If you want a more specific answer you will need to narrow your request. Ray tracing also has merits in volume rendering. Learn more on [volume rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_rendering).